# Looking for svn+hudson+nexus+mysql hosting

Tags: svn, hudson, hosting, jenkins, nexus

I'm looking for subversion(git is OK too) + hudson/jenkins + nexus + mysql hosting for my personal use.

Does anyone offer such options out of the box? Or the only option for me is to rent a linux box and set up it by myself?

Answer (score 2):

Cloudbees has an offer: http://cloudbees.com/dev-features.cb

I don't know if they use Nexus or another repository manager, but there is one included to store your own artifacts and to cache external artifacts.

Sonatype has also an offering: Sonatype Pro Suite, but i think, it is just for download. You can try it as a SaaS, but i couldn't find a regular Cloud offering.